# AttributeError: module 'ytsearch' has no attribute 'geturl'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I want to search for some videos on YouTube by ytsearch as follow:

```
import ytsearch
ytsearch.geturl("CNN News", official_video=False)
```

but when I do this, I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'ytsearch' has no attribute 'geturl'
```

I'm using ytsearch-0.3.7 and cannot find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because ytsearch has no attribute geturl.

```
py -3 -m pip install -U yt-search

import yt_search
yt = yt_search.build("API KEY")
search_result = yt.search("CNN", sMax=10, sType=["video"])
print(search_result.title)
```

It worked for me. For getting API key refer [this](https://www.slickremix.com/docs/get-api-key-for-youtube/)

Output:

```
['CNN', 'New virus cases on the rise in almost half of US states', 'LZ Granderson to Ben Carson: Just stop it. Get out of the way.', 'Thousands mourn George Floyd&#39;s death at Houston memorial', 'Ivanka Trump blames cancel culture for canceled commencement speech', 'CNN Poll: President Trump losing ground to Biden amid chaotic week', 'Colin Powell explains why Trump shouldn&#39;t be re-elected', '¿Cómo debería ser una reforma policial en Estados Unidos?', 'Colin Powell: President Trump has drifted away from the Constitution', 'CNN Reporter Arrested at Minneapolis Protest, Taylor Swift Rips Trump&#39;s &quot;Shooting&quot; Tweet | THR News']
```

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Have you cross-checked your python version?

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: Just try this I think it should work. Actually I got confused. geturl is for getting public URL.

Comment: Where should I add API key ?

Comment: in place of REPLACE ME. yt = yt_search.build("REPLACE ME")

Comment: I did it but it says : yt_search.errors.SearchError: accessNotConfigured

Comment: Can you share your code as it is working fine for me

Comment: It is exactly as yours, but I think I should configure API in google console to make it working

Comment: In your project API library just go to YouTube Data APIV3 and click on credentials and create API key with no restrictions and paste it here.